# Entity delete validation in a microservice environment

Tags: performance, microservices, validation, cqrs, entity

In a microservice environment there are two services: Service A and Service B.

Service A manages an entity called `x` which has one to many relationship with service B's entity called `y`

When a network request hits to Service A to delete a specific `x`, Service A makes an internal network request to service B to validate whether specific `x` being used with any `y` item.

In a microservice environment, is there a better and more efficient way to handle this kind of request and validation among two services?

Also these options already came to table, however not optimal.

1. Managing a cache on Service A about `y` isn't viable.
2. Managing a key/property on each `x` about whether it's being used or not, was
   also considered. However there's a development overhead of migrating
   all the old data with new property.
3. Let the front-end (webapp) directly calls Service B's validation before hitting to delete. However there's a possibility to have a false positive with the timing.

Comment: http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason In our case also `Delete` means changing `status`. I didn't mention that part for brevity.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Well now you have a question about entity deactivate validation instead. It doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 5):

If Peter's approach is not viable for you, an alternative:

- Mark service A's `x` as *DeletePending*
- Send message to service B
- Service B checks its `y`s and either:

  - acknowledges with a *DeleteApproved* message or
  - refuses with a *DeleteRefused* message
- Service A receives a message:

  - *DeleteApproved* --> delete the object
  - *DeleteRejected* --> set `x` back to *Alive* status

BTW: if you have such a tight coupling between services, check your boundaries. Probably A and B should not be separate services in the first place.

Comment: +1 for domain boundary. In general when the question is just 'cascading delete', a message (usually async) is sent to a message queue that other services can pick up and process orphaned data related to the entity. If I saw this kind of bidirectional coupling I would definitely reevaluate the design.

Comment: Isn't this creating an bad practice which Service A should keep an open connection with the front-end's (webapp) request until it receives a message from an sync message queue? 
Only light here is to look for `ack` (e.g: amqp) from Service B if the validation is correct.

Comment: @inckka No, basically this is the request-response pattern. The charming thing is, that if service B is temporarily down and in the process of restarting, the only problem for the user is a slight delay.

Answer (score 3):

Is the following scenario viable for you?

- Mark Service A's `x` entity as *SoftDeleting* / *NotReachable* / *name it...*

  - This should prevent to create new `y` entities in Service B, so Service B has to check `x` before allowing creation of `y`
  - Send a notification about from Service A about `x` status change
- Process Service A's status change event in Service B

  - Mark all `y` entities as *SoftDeleted* / *Inactive* / *name it...*
  - Send a notification from Service B about `x` related records status change
- Process Service B's status change event in Service A

  - Mark Service A;s `x` entity as SoftDeleted* / *Inactive* / *name it...*

---

BTW: Sam Newman's Monolith 2 Microservices book has a dedicated chapter about database migration. Some part of it discussing this topic and fortunately it is [available online](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/monolith-to-microservices/9781492047834/ch04.html) for free.

Comment: This seems to perform a _cascading_ delete, but my reading of the question is that the desire is to _refuse_ the delete if the relationship would be violated. Still, +1 for a well-described possibility.

Comment: The main requirement of OP is to validate before delete. As an example, send a message to front-end (webapp) if any `y`s already using the delete requested `x`. 
However +1 for the provided deletion options.